# Jar to Exe with java FX

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create an .exe file from a -jar file the problem is i am using javafx-sdk-15.0.1 and jdk-15.0.1. For some reason when i use launch4j it wont open the newly created .exe. Can someone help me please. How do i incorporate these two things (javafx-sdk-15.0.1 and jdk-15.0.1) in the .exe.

Note: To run jar from CMD i use this-

java -jar --module-path C:\Users\PC\Desktop\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Taco\Good Taco Shop.jar

I also put the JDK/bin in my path.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the relevant tools that come with your JDK. These are jpackage, jdeps and jlink. Here is a tutorial on how to use them: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX